# Можно ли дважды использовать Функцию header

Tags: php

У меня есть скрипт, в который я вставил фрагмент с кодом,  который использует функцию

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

что значит на странице есть рисунок.
Но она мне сбивает весь остальной код. Как мне локализовать её только для части кода? или может есть возможность использовать второй раз header, что бы перекодировать обратно страницу в

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
```

Comment: что значит сбивает? вы знаете что ее можно вызывать только до отдачи данных клиенту? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: ок, читаю manual дальше, понял насколько вопрос глуп :)

Comment: Котеров - PHP 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header` должен отправляться перед выводом или подключением чего-либо. То есть, если у вас выводится, например `echo "Привет"`, то отправка закончится неудачей. То же самое и с отправкой `header` 2 раза. Заголовок отправлен - теперь вы уже не сможете дальше по коду его отправить. 
(это касается и сессий).
Учтите, что в начале кода даже пробела быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя. Заголовок мы можем установить единожды и только до отправки клиенту